# Boost geometry : intersection using an open interval

Tags: c++, boost, computational-geometry, boost-geometry

I have a polyline and a line segment. One of the endpoints of the line segment is always also a point of the polyline.

Example:
line segment: (1,2),(3,3)
polyline: (3,3),(10,10),(15,30)

I want to use boost geometry in order to find whether the line segment and the polyline have an intersection. However, it is okay for them to intersect at the connected point. In this case, (3,3).

`boost::geometry::intersects` will always return `true` in this case. I would like to make an exception for the common point, but still have it return `true` if there is an intersection at any other point. Is there a clever way to go about this? Or do I have to use `boost::geometry::intersection` and iterate over the results?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to check if the segment intersects with polyline in point other than its connected point.

So you need to check only segments that do not have shared endpoint with red segment (see picture). You may skip those who do have same endpoint with red segment or you may want to handle them in a different way, for example, check if entire segments coincide.

I didn't work with c++ for a long time so I write pseudo code:

```
foreach (segment in polyline) {
    if (
        segment.A != redSegment.A &&
        segment.A != redSegment.B &&
        segment.B != redSegment.A &&
        segment.B != redSegment.B &&
        intersect (segment, redSegment)
    ) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

[image]

Comment: This solution will unfortunately miss any intersections on the adjacent polyline segments of the common point.

Comment: @user129186, I thought you wanted to avoid detecting intersection in the common point. But maybe you want to check if adjacent segments partially coincide with red segment?